# How to check if all letters in UTF-8 string are ASCII?

Tags: utf-8, ascii, pascal

How to check that all string characters are ASCII? It is sad in [documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/LCL_Unicode_Support):

> Unicode characters U+0000 to U+007F (ASCII) are encoded simply as
>   bytes 00h to 7Fh (ASCII compatibility). This means that files and
>   strings which contain only 7-bit ASCII characters have the same
>   encoding under both ASCII and UTF-8. All characters >U+007F are
>   encoded as a sequence of several bytes, each of which has the two most
>   significant bits set.

So I wonder how to check string to be ASCII?

Answer (score 4):

A string is ASCII if all the characters it contains are in the range 0-127.

Answer (score 1):

guava

CharMatcher.ASCII.matchesAllOf(string);

Comment: the question is tagged [tag:pascal], not Java

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to check whether the length of the string in bytes equals the number of Unicode characters (code points). If these values are cached, this might even be the fastest way.